# Unable to Find string length without white space using javascript

Tags: javascript

My sample code is:

```
    <script>

    function Sum(){

        var a = "Hello World";
        var a_length =a.length ;  
          alert(a_length); 

    }

</script>
```

The current length is ::11 . But i want to count the string length that will be 10.
Please help to get proper length using javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work 100 %.

```
 function Sum(){
 var myString = "Hello World";
 var withoutSpace = myString.replace(/ /g,"");
 var length = withoutSpace.length;
 alert(length); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
**For length including white-space:**

$("#id").val().length

**For length without white-space:**

$("#id").val().replace(/ /g,'').length
**For removing only beginning and trailing white-space:**

$.trim($("#test").val()).length
**For example, the string " t e s t " would evaluate as:**

*//" t e s t "*
$("#id").val(); 

**//Example 1**
$("#id").val().length; //Returns 9
**//Example 2**
$("#id").val().replace(/ /g,'').length; //Returns 4
**//Example 3**
$.trim($("#test").val()).length; //Returns 7
```

Try hope it's works for you